# Sendgrid & Firebase Functions: Error Sending Transactional Email with Dynamic Template Data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, sendgrid

Once a new vendor is registered on my Firebase Realtime Database, I want to send the new vendor a welcome email via Sendgrid. I've constructed a Firebase function newVendorEmail() to do this in my app's functions/src/index.ts folder and configured everything there as per https://app.sendgrid.com/guide/integrate/langs/nodejs/verify. I'm also able to retrieve vendor details from Firebase via onCreate() in newVendorEmail() and pass them to the dynamic_template_data part of the msg object without any problem. But when the newVendorEmail() function was triggered in Firebase Functions the email was not sent and I got this response instead in my Firebase Functions Console: TypeError: Object.values is not a function at Mail.setDynamicTemplateData (/user_code/node_modules/@sendgrid/mail/node_modules/@sendgrid/helpers/classes/mail.js:342:12). Help, please?

I've tried upgrading to the latest @sendgrid/mail npm package v6.4.0, tried switching to a new Sendgrid API key, tried storing this new API key in process.env as per Sendgrid's github example https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/use-cases/kitchen-sink.md instead of functions.config(), but to no avail.

```
in node/process.env:

{ SENDGRID_API_KEY:
   'SG....E',
...
}

in functions/src/index.ts:

'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const sendgrid = require('@sendgrid/mail')

// init function
admin.initializeApp()

//init firebase ref const
const ref = admin.database().ref()

// set sendgrid api from process env
sendgrid.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY)

export const newVendorEmail = functions.database
.ref('users/{userId}/profile')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  // call field data using snapshot.val()
  let msg
  const userData = snapshot.val()
  if (userData.type === 'vendor') {
    // set email data
    msg = {
      to: userData.email,
      from: {
        name: 'Blk. Party',
        email: '...@blkparty.com'
      },
      // custom templates
      templateId: '...',
      dynamic_template_data: {
        subject: 'Welcome to Blk. Party!',
        name: userData.name,
        regLink: userData.regLink
      },
    }    
  }
  // send email via sendgrid
  return sendgrid.send(msg) 
})

in package.json:
...
"dependencies": {
  "@sendgrid/mail": "^6.4.0",
  "firebase-admin": "~6.0.0",
  "firebase-functions": "^2.1.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@sendgrid/mail": "^6.4.0",
  ...
}
...
```

I expect emails to be sent without any error.

Comment: I've not used send-grid in a long while, So while this comment does not answer your question have a look at postmark. I have found it a lot friendlier than any other email service.

Comment: Thanks Philip! Though I'd very much like to stick to Sendgrid for now. Will look into postmark on the next app upgrade.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem. In my case, the solution was to switch from node6 to node8 in firebase functions.

Comment: Hey Alejandro, thanks for the prompt answer. Mind elaborating on what you mean by "switch from node6 to node8"? Did you upgrade your npm cli to v8 or just firebase related npm packages?

Comment: He means add `"engines": { "node": "8" } to your /functions/package.json` OR deploy them with `firebase deploy --only functions --runtime nodejs8`

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks Philip and Alejandro!